# Узнаем количество записей

Tags: mysqli, php

Как узнать сколько пользователь отправил записей за день в таблицу orders 
Точнее мне нужно дополнить условие, вот какие функции использовать подскажите правильный запрос к базе

```
$order_on_day = mysqli_query ($c,"SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_by` = '$login'" AND ????); // выбираем все заявки по его автору который = $login(сессии) 
$order_day = mysqli_num_rows($order_on_day); // количество записей
```

Comment: Какая структура таблицы orders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `order_by` = '$login'
  AND order_date between '$datebegin' and '$dateend';
```

Comment: Наверное

    SELECT count(*) ...

Comment: ну там ниже же еще `mysqli_num_rows($order_on_day)` А так конечно лучше `count(*)`